# Is Heroku dependable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have been hosting a site on Heroku for a few months that is very soon to go into production.

Since I began with them, there have been at least three significant outages, one of which was the disastrous Amazon outage last month and another of which is a multi-hour outage happening today.

I believe in Heroku's vision and I think they are a great company, but I am faced with the ultimate problem: if they can't keep sites up and running, everything I like about them doesn't really matter.

#### Is Heroku a reliable provider to run a production site on Rails?

#### Are there any other providers I might look into that have a better reputation for reliability than Heroku?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion, downtime can happen with almost any provider. What you need to see is how well or badly the host handles the downtime and the effort they make in keeping the customer updated about possible resolution.

In my opinion Heroku is a great place to host your app. The advantages and ease of deploying there covers up for the recent (and rare) downtime FOR ME.

Comment: The thing that bothers me most is that when these outages occur, nothing seems to be accessible at all - I wish it were possible to at least reroute users to some read-only page where we can explain what's wrong (or failing that, `status.heroku.com`).

Comment: Perhaps you can re-route your DNS to another location? Perhaps login to ZerigoDNS console? (cant recall the name of the Heroku friendly DNS service) and change the location? Just a workaround.

Comment: If you're using Zerigo -- which is a nice DNS service, btw -- and want the ability to reroute your traffic when Heroku is down, it's important to set up your account outside of Heroku instead of using the Zerigo add-on. Otherwise, you must authenticate with Heroku to get into your Zerigo console. During the recent EC2 outage, authenticating through Heroku was impossible. If you've set up your DNS info through the add-on, Zerigo can easily migrate it to an external account for you, with no down time. (I did this recently. Contact Zerigo.)

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I just assumed Zerigo DNS would provide a non-heroku front end for their heroku customers.

Answer (score 8):

I am user of Heroku with Amazon RDS plugin for the past 7-8 months and my conclusion is there is nothing to appreciate about Heroku except their architecture. Here is why I think:

1. Even though it is sold for $250 million+ they were still NOT using the Amazon multiple zones feature of Amazon. Below is the link how SmugMug survived amazon crash by using Amazon's multiple zones feature.
   http://don.blogs.smugmug.com/2011/04/24/how-smugmug-survived-the-amazonpocalypse/
2. No phone contact support in the event of issues (not application but Heroku's), lot to learn from Rackspace
3. The application I am hosting, people will starve if it goes down for few hours on Friday forget about 60 hours downtime.
4. I see intermittent deployment and connectivity issues. Please visit this link for a confirmation:
   http://status.heroku.com/

I know developers love it because they throw a cheap web process called 'dyno' for free.

Comment: Thanks for your opinions on this. A note on #2: I'm pretty sure Rackspace wouldn't offer phone support either if I was able to host an app with them for free :).

Answer (score 6):

So far Heroku does not offer multiple availability zone redundancy. If you want something more reliable than Heroku you can create your own EC2 instances in multiple availability zones. Of course this will require significantly more server upkeep, admin, and deployment time.

Comment: If you like EC2, you could use [EngineYard](http://www.engineyard.com/)'s managed EC2 cloud platform.

Comment: Actually, Heroku says they do use multiple availability zones. But they do not span regions (all the AZs are in the same region). http://status.heroku.com/incident/151

Answer (score 2):

I have seem Heroku to be reliable. I highly recommended it for starting out and validating your idea. I believe when you start your project you want get it out quickly (to customer or to public).

As mentioned in other comments at some point you might need to switch over to EC2 as you might need zone redundancy and it might actually become cheaper to run of EC2 especially if you already have an SA in the company.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not. As a customer I've experienced multiple critical outages. These things happen and I get that. But what makes Heroku unreliable is their nearly non-existent support when things do go wrong. I would use caution when evaluating Heroku or any provider for that matter and really understand what you're paying for. Paying as much as I did for Heroku I expected more.

As an example one of their databases went offline early on a Sunday. I immediately was made aware, not from Heroku but from our customers and new relic alerts. I contacted Heroku support just to get the ball rolling as I began to troubleshoot. 24 hours later I had literally no responses from Heroku. I could not fork, follow, or take snapshot of the database as they suggest (because they were experiencing issues) so I basically sat on my hand and waited. Hoping that somebody would respond as I frantically attempt to recover somehow, someway.

Was this their fault. No. Not at all. I should/could have done something to mitigate this failure. But as much as I pay for their servies each month I expected something resembling a response to my critical issue.

Comment: I agree 100%. Yesterday evening we all of a sudden saw a whole slew of requests timing out, out of the blue. Our site was immediately unusable. There was no trigger from our side that might have caused it. New Relic showed a huge amount of request starting to pile up. The only thing I can think of: some shared resource is having problems. So you would want to go over this quickly with a support engineer. Not at Heroku. You create a support ticket and start to wait. "Luckily" everything returned back to normal by itself after 3 hours. After 5.5 hours I got the first reply from Heroku. Too late.

Answer (score 2):

Our our app is hosted by Heroku and went down mutliple times over the last 12 months.

Two times it was caused by one of the third-party apps that Heroku offers:

1. We used Zerigo (recommended by Heroku) for our DNS. This has caused our site to go down twice - one time it took over 12 hours te recover. This is absolutely crazy for something like DNS, so we have switched to a more reliable provider.
2. The Redistogo app went down once.

Heroku does bring some benefits, but be careful about the apps you select.

Comment: This is useful - thanks for highlighting that the third-party apps can have an effect. Obvious to some, a nice reminder for others!

Answer (score 0):

In my org i build simple SPA productivity apps, and have been using Heroku to host them for the last year after migrating away from a physical box server to cloud VMs.

I've had multiple days lost due to Heroku development hindering outages. Usually while running apps stay online, and work, when Heroku goes down you can't push updates or restart apps.

Lets also not forget the ridiculous times for scheduled maintenance (usually 2PM EST, midweek....REALLY?)

As of writing this, the Logging system for Heroku has now been acting up (more or less down) for over 24 hour.

Thankfully my apps aren't mission critical. While I like Heroku's ease of use, it's just not worth this much headache for what is nothing other than an AWS middle-man.

That said, I'm moving over to just pure AWS EC2 instances.